# Could we get statistics on where in the world Stack Exchange users come from in 2023?

Tags: discussion

While I realise it is an apples and oranges comparison—with folks having better privacy protections on their own systems and Google Analytics, and how SE uses it changing quite a bit in the [14 years](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/14/where-in-the-world-do-stack-overflow-users-come-from/) since this post—Jeff Atwood posted what SE's analytics system reported as their users were from geographically and this is probably a 'better' metric than the self-reported location. It's not perfect - with proxies and aforementioned blocking of tracking.

Essentially I'm asking if SE *could* get this data, or its modern analog made available for a current time period.

I'm kind of curious to how the 'global' demographic of SE looks like even as an abstraction. While a per site breakdown would be lovely, I'm curious about SO (as the biggest site on the network) as well as the other SE sites in aggregate.

It’s not just out of curiosity; it gives an idea of diversity or lack thereof in the communities. In the short run, we've always had a 'tradition' of encouraging moderators to be from different time zones for coverage and it gives an idea of where our communities are situated.

Comment: Do you mean geographically? I was about to say most people come from either Stack Overflow or Google.

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you expect to be answered and what information you will consider relevant in the responses?

Comment: Should I just say that I'm from Brazil or should I report my professional career path in IT? Or smething else?

Comment: Geographically - essentially along the lines of what was posted on that blog posts - and this would need a staff response to

Comment: No way to answer! *"Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 6.*

Comment: I've clarified what was meant - I probably shouldn't have assumed folks would read the linked post :D

Comment: No no, Not INDIVIDUALLY - More of getting the statistics *from* SE

Comment: @Laurel We can get where people find the site from our available analytics

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the 2022 SO survey asked this question:
https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#developer-profile-key-territories

Although this is not necessarily representative of the SE network as whole.